# Me encontre esta peculiaridad sin mas

Tags: python

Me encontre con esta peculiaridad, estaba haciendo pruebas para un trabajo y sin querer salio esto
Codigo Python

```
file = open("Prueba.txt", "r")
fila = file.readline()
print (fila)
print ()
print ()
for fila in file.readlines():
  print (fila)
print (file.readlines())
```

Al principio creo un

Prueba.txt

```
Primera linea de prueba
Segunda linea de prueba
Tercera linea de prueba
```

Y al querer imprimirlo salio

```
primera linea de prueba



segunda linea de prueba

tercera linea de prueba
[]
```

Yo pense que deberia de salir

```
Primera linea de prueba


Primera linea de prueba

Segunda linea de prueba

Tercera linea de prueba
['primera linea de prueba\n', 'segunda linea de prueba\n', 'tercera linea de prueba']
```

Pero salio lo anterior mostrado, mi teoria es que al utilizar **file.readline()** este corta la palabra o palabras de la primera linea del texto y las imprime, luego al utilizar **file.readlines()** este se supone que debe copiar todas las lineas, pero en este caso solo copio 2 lineas como se muestra anteriormente, y al querer comprobar cuantas lineas hay en ese .txt, salio **[ ]** entonces pienso que el comando **.readline()** corta las palabras de la primera linea quitandolas del .txt y si luego deseas copiar las demas estas solo mostraran las restantes

Comment: algo curioso pero no tanto, creo que sabes como funciona el método `.readline()`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

No. Las palabras no se cortan.

El 99% de los lenguajes, al leer un archivo plano, mantienen un puntero a la posicion de lectura.

Cuando vos haces readline, le estas pidiendo que lea una determinada cantidad de bytes (si le pasas la cantidad) o hasta que encuentra un fin de linea.

Luego, el puntero que indica la posicion sobre la cual se esta leyendo el archivo, pasa al byte siguiente al ultimo que leiste.

Por lo tanto, cuando luego hacer readlines, para leer todo el resto del archivo, lee exactamente todo el resto del archivo. No vuelve al principio y lee todo. Para eso, necesitariamos un metodo que reincie, como [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek), que nos permite volver al principio.